# What will my mobile app that uses 3rd party API do if the private key has been stolen?

Tags: android, security, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

My mobile app uses 3rd party API to access some resources. It has a public key and a private key. For each request, I use the private key to do some hash calculating with some specific data and send the result to the server. The server will verify the result with my private key to make sure the request is valid. The private key won't be sent via network.

However, the private key should be saved in client. I think it's not a difficult thing to find it by other people with some reverse engineering. Is it a more secure way to use the private key?

If the key has been stolen, I can change the private key. But the original app can't be used any more. Is it a better way to solve this problem?

(I setup my own proxy server can solve parts of this problem. Are there any better methods?)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest offloading the 3rd party API access to a REST service that you control. From that point, the private API access key you were provided is safely locked down on a machine you own, and is not as likely to become compromised.

Then you simply update your mobile app to contact your server at a well-defined port and address (optionally doing some sort of verification that you want to process the traffic), then forward that request onward as appropriate. This also allows you very granular control over what particular pieces of the 3rd party API you want exposed to end users.

It is probably a Very Bad Idea (and possibly against your terms of service) to distribute a private key used for 3rd party API access, as a malicious client could potentially cause lots of problems by monkeying around with the service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with this thing but shouldn't you use the Public key to encode your stuff on the client side instead of using the Private key?

That's the point of having a Public/Private keys combination: the public key is freely available to everyone to be used for encoding something but once encoded, the message can only be decoded using the private key; which is safely stored away on a well protected server.